# Apache Camel Database Integration Advantages and Disadvantages

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-camel, spring-jdbc

I am looking for apache camel and I have some question.Apache camel is integration framework but should I use it as data access layer.I have a lot of storedprocedure and complex database logic.In here as I look use apache camel sp content looks like to write your sql queries in form behind.In here what are the advantages of use apache camel sql component or should I use spring jdbc seperately.By the way is there any comment abount spring jdbc advantages or disadvantages.My database is oracle by the way.

Comment: Apache camel is a EIP toolkit. While you could use it as a data access layer you will need to work hard to get the same functionality as a DAL. Also most of the functionality will go to waste. Use the right tools for the job.

Comment: Yes I you are right.Camel is eip toolkit .By the way if you use it,when I use apache camel sql component for only basic crud operations?